# Newtonsoft json is not deserializing when the name of the class is the root element

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

Newtonsoft json DeserializeObject is not parsing the json message when the name of the class is the root element.

```
var json = "  {\r\n \"amount\": {\r\n    \"currency\": \"EUR\",\r\n    \"value\": 99792\r\n  }\r\n}";
var amount = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Amount>(json)
```

and the class

```
class Amount 
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

In that case the Amount properties are `null`. The problem is that the amount is nested in a more complex json and I found out that it is always returned empty because it starts with the "amount". Of course I tried some annotations in the Amount class like [DataContract] and [JsonObject] but still it is empty 
In case of:

```
 var json = "{\r\n    \"currency\": \"EUR\",\r\n    \"value\": 99792\r\n }";
```

Then is parsed properly. The question is how can I deseriale the json in the first case?

Answer (score 5):

You should model your classes like this:

```
public class Amount
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    public Amount Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize `RootObject`:

```
var amount = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

**Note:** You can paste your JSON into [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/), which models your JSON into C# classes for you.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a wrapping class `Root`, which has a single element called `Amount`. For example,

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    public Amount Amount { get; set; }
}
```

You would now need to deserialize to an instance of `Root`. For example,

```
var amount = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to declare another class, you could also use

```
var innerJson = JObject.Parse(json)["amount"].ToString();
var amount = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Amount>(innerJson);
```

Answer (score 4):

> how can I deseriale the json in the first case

Reason why your json is not getting deserialized correctly is because Newtonsoft does not know how to translate `amount` to your class that has two variables, named: `currency` and `value`. To deserialize the json in the first case, you need a class for the first object: `amount`. This object contains another object that matches up with the class you were working with, `Amount`.

When you add the missing class, `RootObject`, and deserialize to that `RootObject`, you will see the json deserialize correctly.

**Classes you need**

```
public class Amount
{
    [JsonProperty("currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    public Amount Amount { get; set; }
}
```

**Use this for Deserialization**

```
var amount = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)
```

**Easy way to find the classes**

I have found [www.json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/)  to be a pretty good resource. Whenever in doubt, copy / paste your json there to get all the classes you need. Copy them in your project and deserialize to RootObject. If your JSON is invalid, you'll find out whats wrong there as well.